# Windows Generic Software Updater API (Example: Steam, Origin)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, updates, api, win32

i just noticed that the updaters of steam and origin look very similar.

[image]

[image]

Is this just some "coincidence" or is there some generic updater api available in Windows that i never noticed?

Comment: Because they both use a progress bar and a Cancel button?

Comment: Because both changed lately to this new style which resemble because they both use the standard windows controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably one has copied the other's user messages and they look similar.

Comment: i just wondered if this is somehow related to windows 8 which i got recently, because i remember the steam updater looked really different (http://www.hlportal.de/images/specials/steam_update1s.gif).